# Autocomplete search using pelias OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim, mapzen, pelias

I don't know if my question is valid or not,I use nominatim search engine but it can't make auto-complete search so I decide to use pelias by mapzen, my question is that is it possible to import data from nominatim to pelias? How?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're running a local instance of Pelias you'll need to run the Pelias OSM data importer to index all the venues and addresses in OSM. Pelias uses elasticsearch so it won't work with Nominatim's database as-is.

Answer (score 3):

Not answering your question about pelias but instead the one about Nominatim and auto-completion.

Take a look at [Photon](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Photon). It supports auto-completion and as far as I know it uses a regular Nominatim database. I've never used it myself though.

It might be also worth to look at other [OSM-based search engines / geocoders](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines).

Comment: Thanks for replying @scai so I'll try with Photon